# App crash with " Thread 90: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)" in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access, nsjsonserialization

```
 -(void)writeAllCategoriesInJson:(NSDictionary *)dict
 {
     NSArray *arry_allCategory = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict, nil];

     NSError *error;
     NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arry_allCategory options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
     if (!jsonData && error){
         NSLog(@"Error creating JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         return;
     }

     NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     // Build the path, and create if needed.
     NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString* fileName = @"Categories.json";
     NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
     }

     // The main act...
     [[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
}
```

Here app crash with

> "Thread 90: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)"

on below line:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arry_allCategory options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

What is the issue on this line. Its working fine all time and in between its crashed. I try my best but the issue is still occuring.

Comment: before that line try to print `dict` and `arry_allCategory ` if it is printing fine then issue with NSData *jsonData line

Comment: @PriyankaPatil ok thank for help. Both `dict` and `arry_allCategory` are fine. and `Nsdata *jsonData` is too fine. i think the issue is with memory allocations. Can you have any idea to resolve this issue with respect to Memory allocation